# Azure GUI for secondary storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using Microsoft Azure as my Cloud Support. I found quite a few documents advertising or explaining how to enable geo-redundant (or geo-replicated) MS Azure storage accounts.I have enable to geo-redundant fetaure in the AZURE. I want to know the blobs which are saved in the secondary storage, Is there any GUI for the same? How do I ensure that my data redundancy is happening properly. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Putting this as comment instead of an answer because the question doesn't really follow SO norms and will most likely be closed. Having said that, do take a look at **Cloud Portam** (http://cloudportam.com/features/storage) [**Disclosure: I built Cloud Portam**] or **Azure Management Studio** (http://www.cerebrata.com). Both of the tools allow you to explore storage from secondary endpoints. **However you should change the redundancy of your storage account from GRS to RA-GRS**. Only then you will be able to read from secondary endpoint.

Comment: You should post this type of question on ServerFault, as it's not programming-specific, but infrastructure specific regarding storage access.

Comment: Gaurav : Thank you for introducing the Azure Management Studio tool.

Comment: here is how we can view blobs in secondary storage - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75767232/6563567

Answer (score 0):

You can follow any of the tools provided above or you can use Azure cloud storage libraries to get access over the same.

Ref - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-redundancy/#read-access-geo-redundant-storage

***Read-access geo-redundant storage***

When you enable read-only access to your data in the secondary region, your data is available on a secondary endpoint, in addition to the primary endpoint for your storage account. The secondary endpoint is similar to the primary endpoint, but appends the suffix –secondary to the account name. For example, if your primary endpoint for the Blob service is **myaccount.blob.core.windows.net**, then your secondary endpoint is **myaccount-secondary.blob.core.windows.net**. The access keys for your storage account are the same for both the primary and secondary endpoints.