# Azure Secondary Storage (RAGRS)

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We have configured RAGRS storage with Azure between North Europe (Primary) and West Europe (Secondary). Is the fail over of the storage to the secondary location automatic and handled by Microsoft? How do we go about accessing the secondary location in the event of a DR scenario? I've seen a couple of articles stating that you need to add the prefix of "-secondary" but I'm not sure where and how we would authenticate? Can we access the VHDS files in the second location?

Many Thanks, David

Answer (score 2):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35660112/272109), you may read from your secondary by appending `-secondary` to the storage account name, in the connection string. You would still use the same primary (or secondary) access key.

Using the secondary connection string, you may access any blob in storage, but remember that it's *eventually-consistent*.

As far as Azure itself failing over to a secondary: That's part of Azure's DR, and the rules governing such a failover aren't publicly documented as far as I can tell.

Comment: Many thanks. I am really struggling on how to access the "secondary" replica of our storage. At present we are using an Azure File Share which is working well i.e. \\storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net\apps\ . The username is then \\storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net\storageaccountname and the  password is one of two keys which works fine.  If I try to access the replica copy of the above using \\storageaccountname-secondary.file.core.windows.net\apps\ . I get asked for authentication so it must be seeing the location path but the username and or password don't work. Please help

Comment: @dsmith1984 Please ask a new question. Your comment is about file shares, which is something different.

Comment: Thanks David I will post a new question regarding the file shares. Are you able to answer how I could access the VHDS in the replica location in the event of us ever needing to take a copy and mount the copy offline (if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

> Is the fail over of the storage to the secondary location automatic
>   and handled by Microsoft?

Yes, it is handled by Microsoft. However please keep in mind that because your storage account's redundancy level is set as `RAGRS` instead of `GRS`, at any point of time you can read from the secondary location. Simply change your storage account connection string from `yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net` to `yourstorageaccount-secondary.blob.core.windows.net`.

> Can we access the VHDS files in the second location?

Yes, you can access VHD files but you can only read from them. Remember `RA` in `RAGRS` stands for `Read Access`. If you try to mount these VHDs or try to write to them, the operation would fail.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the quick response. "yourstorageaccount.\\tlafsprodne001-secondary.blob.core.windows.net\" doesn't appear to work but if I try "yourstorageaccount.\\tlafsprodne001-secondary.file.core.windows.net\" I get prompted for authentication but I am unable to get past this stage? Also, can you explain the steps of how we would access the content on the VHDS file if we ever needed to retrieve content? Basically if Azure failed in North Europe would we have to do anything to failover storage?

Comment: You can't connect to your blob storage account that way. Access to blob storage needs to be authorized (which is something I can't describe in the comments unfortunately as it is too long) but you can use one of the many storage client libraries to view the contents of your blob storage and even download them to your local computer. If Azure fails in North Europe and Microsoft feels that it is indeed a disaster situation, it will automatically fail over to secondary storage. You don't have to do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the fail over of the storage to the secondary location automatic
> and handled by Microsoft?

Not always. You may have to manually fail over sometimes. [In extreme circumstances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance#microsoft-managed-failover) where a region is lost due to a significant
disaster, Microsoft may initiate a regional failover.

> How do we go about accessing the secondary location in the event of a
> DR scenario?
> I've seen a couple of articles stating that you need to add the prefix
> of "-secondary"

The account name will remain the same as primary. But the blob endpoint or table endpoint should have **-secondary suffix**. Here is [the doc](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/download-the-blob-using-secondary-endpoint-in-ragrs-storage/ba-p/2403750) explaining the same using azure GUI storage explorer.

**Using access key**

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorageaccount;AccountKey=35tCZY3DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;BlobEndpoint=https://mystorageaccount-secondary.blob.core.windows.net
```

**Using SAS token**

```
https://mystorageaccount-secondary.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2021-12-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-02-14T18:32:45Z&st=2022-03-16T11:32:45Z&spr=https&sig=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

However, Azure file share might not support the secondary endpoint. Its available only for blob, queue, table and data lake.

> but I'm not sure where and how we would authenticate?

Use the same access key or SAS token that you use for the primary endpoint.

Also note that there is redundancy option like RA-GRS and RA-GZRS where reads can be directed to the secondary storage even without a failover. Application can be configured to write to primary and read from secondary (with eventual consistency).